# Angular/Node authenticate User

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ionic-framework

I have a node server that is running. and it sends a post to a Twitter Timeline, which I have an Ionic/Angular Application the consumes the Node Server and sends the message.

however, the problem is that in the node server my user's Twitter account info is hard coded and I would like to know how I can send the user's details that I get from the Twitter connect Plugin.

here is my node sever

```
const express = require('express');
const Twitter = require('twit');

const app = express();
const client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key:         '...',
  consumer_secret:      '...',
  access_token:         '...',
  access_token_secret:  '...',
});


app.use(require('cors')());
app.use(require('body-parser').json());

app.post('/post_tweet', (req, res) => {

  tweet = req.body;

  client
    .post(`statuses/update`, tweet)
    .then(tweeting => {
      console.log(tweeting);

      res.send(tweeting);
    })

   .catch(error => {
    res.send(error);
  });


});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running'));
```

twitter service in my angular/ionic app

```
export class TwitterserviceService {
  api_url = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } 

  tweet(tweetdata: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.api_url}/post_tweet/`, {status: tweetdata})
        .pipe(map(tweet => {

            alert("tweet posted")

            return tweet;
        }));
}
}
```

and here is my angular Code that sends a tweet to the node server

```
sendTweet() {  
  this.api.tweet('sent from phone')
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log('yes')
                },
                error => {
                  'failed'
                });
}
```

connect plugin

```
twitterLogin() {
    this.twitter.login().then((res: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('twitterLogin', "true");
      this.firebaseService.twitterDetail(this.userId, res);


      this.twitterUser = true;
      if(this.twitterUser == true){
        this.twitter.showUser()
        .then(user => {
          console.log("User: " + user +
                        'username ' + res.username+ " " + user.username);

        });
      }


    }, (err: any) => {
      alert('error: ' + err);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Could you show an example of "hard coded" user?

Comment: the top piece of code is the hardcode(where I enter the client key etc) I want my app to post the user's details that I get from the Twitter Connect Plugin in my Angular Ionic App and post that details to my node server. so that when the user wants to post a message to twitter. it Posts a message to the User's account and not the account that has been hardcoded into the node sever

Comment: What you requires is authorization from user to post on behalf of him/her. This usually requires oauth style authentication. Your application should be registered in Twitter. To perform authorization refer to the following process - https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/3-legged-oauth

The process has been described in the following URL. Check the Application-user authentication section
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/oauth

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set params to `AuthenticationHeaders` while calling the API service which will implement `Interceptor` interface in `Angular`.

You can use this for reference [HttpRequest with Interceptor in Angular](https://dev.to/ibrahima92/better-http-request-with-interceptors-in-angular-8-and-beyond-fdn)